# Web Hosting in aaPanel

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I have just installed aaPanel. When I try to use postgresSql, I cannot open it. Where and how can I use is as a pgAdmin? In sidebar there is panel called Database. In there only phpmyadmin exits. Please help

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about managing your servers should be asked on [sf].

Answer (score 0):

For my django projects in aaPanel there is support for mysql as database and phpmyadmin as administration tool.

It seems that you have to install the pgAdmin tool at the section of App Store in the left sidebar of aaPanel. You can search for it by typing "pg" in the search field. After the installation i think you will be able by clicking on Manager link at the section of databases to open the pgAdmin and handle your database.

If you still have a problem you can ask for support here : [aaPanel forum](https://forum.aapanel.com/)